# Is there a way to programmatically determine that a function is actually an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-5, object-literal

In Javascript, functions are objects. Yet `typeof` of a function returns `function` instead of `object` for [ECMAScript compatibility reasons](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object).

Is this `function` type actually some kind of wrapper for `object` that can be determined somehow? Or in Javascript, is a `function` actually fundamentally different from `object`s?

I do understand that functions are *effectively* and *practically* objects. But are they *by definition* actually completely separate from Objects in Javascript, or is there a way to programmatically reveal the Object that the Function is made of?

Comment: `Object(someFunction) === someFunction`.

Comment: A `Function` is an "extension" of an `Object` ... like every non-primitive in javascript (some more indirect than others, but every non-primitive in javascript is an Object (sort of, you can create an object that isn't even an Object)

Comment: I like where @SebastianSimon is going with this, but `typeof Object(someFunction)` is still `function` and not `object`. So that is really only showing that the _functions_ are equal. Same as `typeof Object("s")` is `string`.

Comment: @Bravo I have tried in my question to make it clear that I actually _do_ understand how functions are objects. But what I'm trying to figure out is if this can be demonstrated programmatically from within javascript.

Comment: @brentonstrine `typeof Object("s")` is `"object"`. `typeof` unfortunately doesn’t mean “the type of a value”. It’s broken for `null`. It has the additional feature of reporting unresolvable references as `"undefined"`, conflating the actual `undefined` value. And it has the _additional_ feature of reporting objects with a [[Call]] internal slot as `"function"`. That’s all it is: features of a weird operator. The _actual_ [ECMAScript types](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types) are listed in the specification, as is the behavior of [`typeof`](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator).

Comment: My mistake. I was thinking about how Object("s") returns a String wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

As the spec [says](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-overview):

> an object is a member of the built-in type Object; and a function is a callable object

So

> Or in Javascript, is a function actually fundamentally different from objects?

Not really, except for the fact that a function is callable - more precisely, that it has a [`[[Call]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) internal method.

Functions inherit from objects in a very similar way that objects inherit from objects. For example, for a given function:

```
function foo(){}
foo.a = 'a';
```

There is:

- The foo function, which is an object, and has a `[[Call]]` internal method, as well as an `a` property, and a few other properties that functions have (like `name`)
- The foo function inherits from `Function.prototype`
- `Function.prototype` inherits from `Object.prototype`
- `Object.prototype` inherits from nothing - that's the start of the prototype chain

> is there a way to programmatically reveal the Object that the Function is made of?

That's not really how it is - the function itself is an object. If the function object has properties, it'll be visible directly on the function. For example, above, referencing `foo.a` will give you the string `'a'`. The `a` property isn't separate from the function - it's directly on the function object.

Comment: I understand the ways in which a function is an object practically. And yet `typeof fn` is not `object`. So while we humans can understand the spec and can understand that functions are objects (or are extensions of objects) for all the reasons you described, I'm trying to find a way to show this _programmatically_, from within Javascript itself.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show that functions can have arbitrary own key-value pairs, like other objects? `function fn() {} fn.a = 'a'; console.log(fn.hasOwnProperty('a'));` will give `true`, is that what you're looking for?